# Inspection code reviews, is it outdated today?

Tags: development-process, code-quality, code-reviews

I'm a big proponent of peer reviews on every change, like with pull requests etc, however I'm questioning if this type of review alone is enough.

For one, I have trouble with reviewers 'missing the forest for the trees' so to speak. Their focus is on the changeset and often fail to consider future or past integration, the overall feature being developed or even the overall component. e.g. for a single web service feature, we've broken it down to two major tasks, front & backend. backend is complete and reviewed, frontend is complete and reviwed, both are individually logically sound, but no one has picked up that the backend is exposing more data than the frontend is actually consuming. Or commonly, the first task/review assumed that a certain check will be implemented in a later task, but it never does. I believe a final review after a feature or module is complete could help.

Secondly, pull requests are meant to be fast and thus not thorough. But with security issues and other critical functions, a thorough inspection and even a checklist of questions or items to consider is needed. Again, a separate inspection process apart from pull requests is needed.

However, i don't see any support for this at all. Popular wisdom seems to be formal inspection reviews are outdated and a hindrance from the past. It's all lightweight change-based code reviews. Even the tools aren't supportive of it, like with git pull requests being conflated as a review system.

So I'm here, to seek validation for my views, or condemnation that I'm stuck in a past world. And also to seek advise, if i'm doing something wrong with my code reviews or how else I can deal with them better.

Answer (score 1):

You, your team and your organisation are the only ones that can define what should be expected of a code review or even if one is needed at all.

In some organisations code review is mandatory to ensure some quality, in others it's developer works and they don't know/don't care.

Also if code review is mandatory in your team, what should be reviewed must be agreed by the team. It will decide the minimum effort to be done, but it dies not mean someone can't go beyond if it feels the need to. But in this case it must not block any process or delivery because a cow boy wants to do a perfect review. Be mindful of others.

Now about some thing you said

> I have trouble with reviewers 'missing the forest for the trees'
> Their focus is on the changeset and often fail to consider future or past integration

One way to avoid this is to do pair programming. By doing so the review will be done at the same time as the work. Also Since two people are working together they both know the past, future and content of the work.

If pair programming is not possible the charge is not on the reviewer but the reviewee to explain things. A reviewer does not have all keys in hand to know why a change is performed, or all functional implication of the change. The more explanation there is, there more dot will be connected by a reviewer. Also, let's face it: not everyone know everything about a code base, it's past state, current state, or even more what tomorrow will be.

> both are individually logically sound, but no one has picked up that the backend is exposing more data than the frontend is actually consuming.
> If two different group of people are reviewing two different part of code there is no way they could catch that. In this case one way would be to have at least one common people in both review. Another would be to have the same people work on front and back (maybe in pair programming if their skill sets are different).
>
> Or commonly, the first task/review assumed that a certain check will
> be implemented in a later task, but it never does.

Never assume anything, always verify or ensure.

> Secondly, pull requests are meant to be fast and thus not thorough.
> Once again it depends on what your team decided.
>
> But with security issues and other critical functions, a thorough
> inspection and even a checklist of questions or items to consider is
> needed. Again, a separate inspection process apart from pull requests
> is needed.

Not necessarily separated. A checklist may good to remember everything that needs to be reviewed. If security is at charge of your team, then it must be reviewed at the same time as everything else.

> It's all lightweight change-based code reviews.

The simplest the change the simplest the review.

> Popular wisdom seems to be formal inspection reviews are outdated and
> a hindrance from the past.

We are long past the era when a developer worked for months on a feature before merging it. At that time, yes a thorough inspection was needed because the smallest error meant either the work was not delivered and next delivery could be months later or issues stayed till next delivery (again maybe months later).
Nowadays with continuous integration, continuous delivery and above else short delivery iterations (in shared branch not necessarily in production) it means that error are caught sooner (before delivery) but also that error that do pass can be easily fixed and quickly delivered.

In conclusion :
Your review process is entirely up to your team to decides. It must be done considering the constraint of your organisation, your technical environment, your culture and your goals. What is good or wanted by the majority of the internet may not be adapted to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the arguments in the question are based on false premises.

I don't think it makes much sense to consider "the forest" at the time of the pull request. There is plenty of opportunity during the time that you create and refine the concept, work through impacts on architecture and design, and then start to write the code that you have to align on how the changes fit into the broader picture of the system. At code review time, which usually occurs after most or all of the code has been written and may even include the automated tests, it's simply too late to have discussions about the feature in the context of the architecture of the system. There's too much waste.

The idea that "pull requests are meant to be fast" is also a misconception. I've definitely used pull requests in the context of formal reviews before. Following a standard formal inspection process, I have created the pull request and made sure that it references the issue(s) that it addresses. I add the reviewers to the PR and set up a meeting invite. The reviewers have time to read through before the meeting, and then we meet and walk through the code. There is some risk in this in that the branch that the code lives in needs to be synchronized with the upstream branch and there may be conflicts that must be resolved, but that depends on your team's structure and workflow.

I think it's true that most code reviews are much lighter weight now and formal walkthrough and inspection methods aren't as highly used. However, there are also far more tools now to support automation of the code review process. Linters can be run locally or even integrated into the IDE to enforce code style. Static analysis tools can flag code smells, performance issues, or security problems locally or as part of a CI/CD pipeline. Automated tests at the unit, integration, and acceptance level provide confidence in the changes and there are tools to assess the coverage and quality of these tests.

The first thing I'd start with is answering one question: What do I want to get out of a code review? The answer will drive how you think about the process and how it fits into the broader set of activities that you do as part of developing your system.